# I need a way for Kafka consumer to commit a particular message

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Let's imagine a stream of messages in a kafka partition.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Is there a way for a consumer to commit one message(let's say 2), so that if that particular consumer started reading messages from the beginning all over again, it would only consume uncommitted messages?

```
1, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Apache Kafka doesn't support single record acknowledgement AFAIK. So, when a message gets acknowleged (say `3`), all prevoiusly seen messages are considered *read*.

You can process your topic with some `filter` processor which will drop messages by some condition. The output topic of this processor could be consumed by your app then.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the use case, but you could use a compacted topic

Say you send these messages

```
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3) 
(4, 4)
(5, 5)
```

And you don't want to see value 2 anymore, then you send one more record

```
(2, null)
```

After compaction, all keys with 2 get removed